# How do I start the Mage faction quest line?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've managed to get to about level 30 in Kingdoms of Amalur without ever bumping into the mage faction quest line, though I've seen mention elsewhere that such a thing exists.

Where do I need to go and who do I need to talk to for this quest chain to begin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can join the Mage Faction, the Scholia Arcana, in the city of Ysa, which you go to for an early part of the Main Quest.

You're looking for a building on the south-east-ish edge of the city. It's across from one of the buildings with a  trainer in it (in this case, sagecrafting).

Do note that there's another Sagecrafting trainer wandering around Ysa - ignore him, you want to find the building with the stationary trainer.

Comment: Specifically, you must speak to **Docent Augra Tenet** in the Scholia Arcana Embassy building in Ysa to begin the quest "Trial by Fire."